# Console.table to display without the quotation around strings

Tags: javascript, console

If you do `console.table(['hello', 'table'])` then you get

```
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│ (index) │ Values  │
├─────────┼─────────┤
│    0    │ 'hello' │
│    1    │ 'there' │
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

I do not want the quotation around the strings `'`. How can I remove this so I get

```
┌─────────┬───────┐
│ (index) │ Value │
├─────────┼───────┤
│    0    │ hello │
│    1    │ there │
└─────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: console.table is part of the developer tools, so, grab the source of the browser, make the changes to the console.table code, then recompile the browser - i.e. you can't

Comment: Why does this matter? This is just for debugging, it shouldn't be used as part of an application's real UI.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might need to use some `npm` package instead:

- https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer
- https://github.com/Automattic/cli-table